# Silverlight RichTextBox and UIElementCollection

Tags: silverlight-4.0, telerik, rich-text-editor

I am currently trying to implement the Silverlight RadRichText in a user control with the example shown on [this RichTextBox example](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radrichtextbox-features-data-providers.html). Using the DataProvider, the code that they are showing is this (sorry for the formatting):

`<UserControl x:Class="DataProvidersDemo.MainPage"
            xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:telerikDocumentsXAML="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Xaml;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Xaml">
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
         Background="White">
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition />
           <RowDefinition />
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <telerikDocumentsXAML:XamlDataProvider x:Key="xamlDataProvider"
           Xaml="{Binding ElementName=radTextBox, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
           RichTextBox="{Binding ElementName=radRichTextBox}" />
       <telerik:RadRichTextBox Margin="2" Name="radRichTextBox" />
       <TextBox Margin="2" Grid.Row="1"  Name="radTextBox" />
   </Grid>
</UserControl>`

and I get that error : A value of type 'XamlDataProvider' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'.

And I don't have a clue where to look anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<telerikDocumentsXAML:XamlDataProvider x:Key="xamlDataProvider" Xaml="{Binding ElementName=radTextBox, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" RichTextBox="{Binding ElementName=radRichTextBox}" />
```

needs to be put into your UserControl Resource section.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <telerikDocumentsXAML:XamlDataProvider x:Key="xamlDataProvider" Xaml="{Binding ElementName=radTextBox, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" RichTextBox="{Binding ElementName=radRichTextBox}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```